# Is there an open-source tool to view component percentages of pdf file?

Tags: pdf, open-source

Adobe Acrobat optimizer has an Audit Space Usage function that displays the percentage of the file size of each type of component, e.g. images, fonts, etc. See [this page](http://www.planetpdf.com/creative/article.asp?ContentID=6112) for an example.

Is there an open-source tool that does the same thing?

Comment: This sounds like a pretty specialized function, I would say chances are low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a program that does this. It is pdfsizeopt.py from this [location](http://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/).
I used the command

```
python pdfsizeopt.py --stats target.pdf
```

and got an output like this:

```
info: This is pdfsizeopt.py rUNKNOWN.
info: computing statistics for PDF: target.pdf
info: PDF size is 6805076 bytes
info: stat contents_objs = 316509 bytes (5%)
info: stat font_data_objs = 147998 bytes (2%)
info: stat header = 16 bytes (0%)
info: stat image_objs = 5999532 bytes (88%)
info: stat linearized_xref = 17161 bytes (0%)
info: stat other_objs = 317204 bytes (5%)
info: stat separator_data = 27 bytes (0%)
info: stat trailer = 134 bytes (0%)
info: stat wasted_between_objs = 18 bytes (0%)
info: stat xref = 6477 bytes (0%)
info: end of stats
```

Comment: This still works, but it hasn't been updated since 2019 and only runs on python2.7, so it might not be a viable solution for much longer.